# CCSpriteFrame warning..AnchorPoint won't work as expected.Regenerate the .plist?

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

i have three simple images of a hen which i am trying to animate(hen walking) using a very good tutorial by ray wenderlich

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d

but i am getting this warning again and again and no sprite shows up on the screen
original Width/Height not found on the CCSpriteFrame. AnchorPoint won't work as expected. Regenerate the .plist
i tried resizing and untrimming but the erro persists...i cannot figure out the problem?? heres my code

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"hentry.plist"];        

    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"hentry.png"];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];

    // Load up the frames of our animation
    NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 2; i <= 3; ++i) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", i]]];
    }
    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

    // Create a sprite
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    self.bear = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"2.png"];
    _bear.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
    [_bear runAction:_walkAction];
    [spriteSheet addChild:_bear];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Zwoptex** menu, select **References...**
Select **Sprite Sheet** tab
Change "Coordinates Format" to **cocos2d** instead of **Zwoptex Generic**

[image]

Comment: In version 0.99.4 of Cocos2D and 1.16 of Zwoptex, it appears that exporting to Cocos2D coordinates isn't working. I managed to generate the correct .plist file by exporting to Zwoptex Flash Version. If this doesn't work, export the texture and coordinates manually (File > Export Texture, File > Export Coordinates) as Zwoptex Flash.