# Need help in resolving the simple cocos2d error?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am using following code:

```
  // Add the stuff from below!  
    CCSprite* background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background-1.png"];
    background.tag = 1;
    background.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [self addChild:background];


    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:
     @"wave1.plist"];

    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode 
                                      batchNodeWithFile:@"wave1.png"];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];
    NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:
         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"wave-r-l-000%d.png", i]]];
        //wave-r-l-0001
    }

    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation 
                             animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    self.bear = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bear1.png"];        
    _bear.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                       [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
    [_bear runAction:_walkAction];
    [spriteSheet addChild:_bear];
```

But unfortunately it gives following error:

```
2011-07-12 09:43:33.471 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: cocos2d v1.0.0-rc3
2011-07-12 09:43:33.479 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
2011-07-12 09:43:33.650 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: OS version: 4.3.1 (0x04030100)
2011-07-12 09:43:33.654 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Imagination Technologies
2011-07-12 09:43:33.658 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: PowerVR SGX 535
2011-07-12 09:43:33.661 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 IMGSGX535-58.6
2011-07-12 09:43:33.667 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 2048
2011-07-12 09:43:33.670 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH: 16
2011-07-12 09:43:33.674 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
2011-07-12 09:43:33.677 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
2011-07-12 09:43:33.680 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
2011-07-12 09:43:33.684 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
2011-07-12 09:43:33.687 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
2011-07-12 09:43:33.690 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: compiled with NPOT support: NO
2011-07-12 09:43:33.694 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: compiled with VBO support in TextureAtlas : NO
2011-07-12 09:43:33.697 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: compiled with Affine Matrix transformation in CCNode : YES
2011-07-12 09:43:33.700 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
2011-07-12 09:43:33.854 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file 'wave1.png' as texture
2011-07-12 09:43:33.905 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: WARNING: originalWidth/Height not found on the CCSpriteFrame. AnchorPoint won't work as expected. Regenerate the .plist
2011-07-12 09:43:33.910 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: WARNING: originalWidth/Height not found on the CCSpriteFrame. AnchorPoint won't work as expected. Regenerate the .plist
2011-07-12 09:43:33.914 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: WARNING: originalWidth/Height not found on the CCSpriteFrame. AnchorPoint won't work as expected. Regenerate the .plist
2011-07-12 09:43:33.917 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: WARNING: originalWidth/Height not found on the CCSpriteFrame. AnchorPoint won't work as expected. Regenerate the .plist
2011-07-12 09:43:33.921 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: WARNING: originalWidth/Height not found on the CCSpriteFrame. AnchorPoint won't work as expected. Regenerate the .plist
2011-07-12 09:43:33.925 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: WARNING: originalWidth/Height not found on the CCSpriteFrame. AnchorPoint won't work as expected. Regenerate the .plist
2011-07-12 09:43:33.928 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: WARNING: originalWidth/Height not found on the CCSpriteFrame. AnchorPoint won't work as expected. Regenerate the .plist
2011-07-12 09:43:33.932 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: WARNING: originalWidth/Height not found on the CCSpriteFrame. AnchorPoint won't work as expected. Regenerate the .plist
2011-07-12 09:43:33.935 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: WARNING: originalWidth/Height not found on the CCSpriteFrame. AnchorPoint won't work as expected. Regenerate the .plist
2011-07-12 09:43:33.941 TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Frame 'bear1.png' not found
2011-07-12 09:43:33.946 TestBear[205:707] *** Assertion failure in -[CCSprite initWithSpriteFrame:], /Users/shahbazali/Documents/TestBear/libs/cocos2d/CCSprite.m:229
2011-07-12 09:43:34.006 TestBear[205:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid spriteFrame for sprite'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x31fbe64f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x31132c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x31fbe491 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 68
    3   Foundation                          0x30c30573 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 62
    4   TestBear                            0x0008cf08 -[CCSprite initWithSpriteFrame:] + 200
    5   TestBear                            0x0008bfcc +[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:] + 88
    6   TestBear                            0x0008c098 +[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:] + 120
    7   TestBear                            0x00003f04 -[HelloWorldLayer init] + 744
    8   TestBear                            0x00067bf0 +[CCNode node] + 76
    9   TestBear                            0x000041e4 +[HelloWorldLayer scene] + 100
    10  TestBear                            0x00003530 -[TestBearAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] + 1028
    11  UIKit                               0x322f885d -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 832
    12  UIKit                               0x322f2b65 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 272
    13  UIKit                               0x322c77d7 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1114
    14  UIKit                               0x322c7215 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 44
    15  UIKit                               0x322c6c53 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5090
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x304a6e77 PurpleEventCallback + 666
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x31f95a97 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 26
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x31f9783f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 166
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x31f9860d __CFRunLoopRun + 520
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x31f28ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x31f28dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
    22  UIKit                               0x322f1d49 -[UIApplication _run] + 372
    23  UIKit                               0x322ef807 UIApplicationMain + 670
    24  TestBear                            0x000030b4 main + 100
    25  TestBear                            0x00003018 start + 52
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

Please help

Comment: Following link will be helpful to you-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322135/ccspriteframe-warning-anchorpoint-wont-work-as-expected-regenerate-the-plist

Answer (score 4):

I know the topic is a bit old but it might help some people.

The error comes from this line:

```
self.bear = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bear1.png"];
```

*TestBear[205:707] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Frame 'bear1.png' not found*

It means that the CCSpriteFrameCache does not containt sprime frame named "bear1.png". Here you add only 1 plist file ("wave1.plist") and and it contains no sprime frame named "bear1.png". So check you plist file and re-generate it if necessary.

An another common error is to use "spriteWithSpriteFrameName:" instead of "spriteWithFile:" if your sprite is not inside a spritesheet.

I hope i'll help.